# HTML5 Data URI fails when a base64 null is followed by an =?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, base64, firefox4, data-uri

I'm doing some pretty unholy things with JavaScript, and I've run into a weird problem.

I am creating binary data that fills a buffer of a static size. If the content doesn't fill the buffer, the remainder is filled with null characters.

The next step is to convert to base64.

The size (bytes) isn't always a multiple of 3, so I may need to add padding to the end. The last bytes in the buffer are always null (actually, it's about a kb of nulls).

When I convert this to base64 on Firefox and Chrome, I get an `ERR_INVALID_URL` when I have a trailing '=', but it downloads fine when I don't.

For example:

```
var url = "data:application/octet-stream;base64,";

window.open(url + "AAAA"); // works
window.open(url + "AAAA="); // doesn't work
window.open(url + "icw="); // works
```

My files work, but they're not up to spec.

**Is there a reason why this is invalid base64?** More importantly, is this a bug or part of the specification?

Edit:

I've posted an answer that gives some of the oddities between Firefox and Chrome. Does anyone know what the standard specifies? Or is it one of those loose specifications that causes fragmentation?  I'd like something definitive if possible.

Comment: I added another thing that works (non-null string with equals sign).

Comment: Wow there sure is a lot of confusing and contradictory information out there about data URLs and the encoding.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The padding character `=` is used to fill up to a multiple of four code characters. As every three bytes of input are mapped onto four bytes of output, a number of input bytes that is not a multiple of three requires padding (a remainder of one byte requires `==` and a remainder of two bytes requires `=`).

In you case `AAAA` already is a valid code word and doesn’t require padding.

Comment: So, AAAA is 3 null bytes. What if I have 4 null bytes?

Comment: @tjameson: That would be `AAAAAA==`.

Comment: are you sure that in "base64url" encoding that there's any need for pad characters?  I can't find anything conclusive one way or the other.

Comment: I'm marking this as correct because it got me on the right track. I now have a working (*crosses fingers*) implementation.

Answer (score 2):

Why would you imagine that adding an "=" character to the end of the string would work?  That's not a valid character in base64.

The character set is upper- and lower-case letters; the digits; and "+" and "/". Anything else is therefore not valid in a base64 string.

*edit* — well for URLs it seems that instead of "+" and "/" you use "-" and "_" (for positions 62 and 63 in the character set).

*edit some more* — this is a very confusing topic due to the existence of different, apparently authoritative but contradictory, sources of information. For example, [the Mozilla description of the data URL scheme](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/The_data_URL_scheme) makes no mention of using the "filename-friendly" alternate encoding. Same goes for the IETF data url RFC.  However, other IETF documents clearly discuss and specify the variation with "-" and "_" replacing the problematic (for file names) "+" and "/".

Therefore, I declare myself ignorant :-)  Gumbo is probably right, that the complaints you're getting are about incorrect padding (that is, padding when no padding is actually necessary).

Comment: On that very same page you can find that there is no pad character in the base64 notation used with URLs.

Comment: Oh and it also looks like instead of "+" and "/" you use "-" and "_" (unsurprising, I guess, for URLs :-)

Comment: Well, I've tried it with base64 strings that don't have a trailing null and it works fine.

Comment: @Pointy Is there any way to specify an output size?

Comment: What do you mean by "an output size"?

Comment: Size, in bytes, of the file once downloaded.  I don't think it's possible, like how it's not possible to change the filename.

Comment: I recall another data url question wherein somebody asked (I think) about that; or maybe it was about specifying a file name.  The [URL scheme](http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc2397) has a spec for parameters, but I can't find any references to any software that uses or recognizes them.  In particular, that IETF document, like the Mozilla page, makes no mention of a file size specifier.

Comment: @Pointy Grr, well, I guess I'll have to wait until HTML5 is 'officially released'. I'm not too hopeful about it though...

Answer (score 2):

Notes about different browsers:

- Chrome

  - `datalength % 4 === 1`- a single equals is necessary
  - `datalength % 4 === 2`- two equals are necessary
- Firefox- equals signs are optional, but follow the same conventions as in Chrome

This is the line I used to test it (I replaced AAAAAA== with a different string each time):

`var url = "data:application/octet-stream;base64,AAAAAA=="; window.open(url);`

Also, both Firefox and Chrome use `+` & `/`, not `-` and `_`.

Source:

My tests on Ubuntu 11.04 with Chrome 11 and Firefox 4.

Edit:

The code I need this for is a [tar utility for Javascript](https://github.com/beatgammit/tar-js). My code works as is, but I'd like to be as standards-compliant as possible, and I'm missing a byte I think. No biggie because tar in Linux recognizes it.

Comment: Yes, I think you're right.  This is one of those questions wherein I find out that stuff I thought I knew about, well, I really don't.  Or didn't :-)  Thanks for asking it!

Comment: @Pointy It's ok. Your response made me look a little deeper into the problem. It's weird because the documentation on Wikipedia didn't match my tests...